# Why is Magneto's cape asymmetrical in Days of Future Past?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, magneto

In the film X-Men: Days of Future Past, Magneto's cape, both in the future and in the past, Magneto's cape is weirdly uneven.

Why is this the case? Is there some story-based reason for this? Or is it simply a costume designer's flourish?

[image: Future]
[image]

Comment: Apparently [Bishop](http://i1.wp.com/www.slashfilm.com/wp/wp-content/images/X-Men-DOFP-Bishop.jpg?resize=242%2C313) was going to have much the same cape design, which actually makes sense since he slings a massive gun on the left-hand side of his belt. My guess is that having designed a cape for Bishop (and then done away with it), they decided to give it to Magneto.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The costume designer for X-Men, X-Men 2, X-Men Origins: Wolverine, and Days of Future Past (as well as the upcoming X-Men: Apocalypse), [Louise Mingenbach](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0591281/), prefers to dress Magneto in asymmetrical styles. [She told GQ](http://www.gq.com/gallery/x-men-days-of-future-past-costumes#4) that she intentionally made Michael Fassbender's topcoat asymmetrical, as well:

> The suit's molten lava red, one of Magneto's colors, and the coat is
>   asymmetrical, like the pieces I made for Ian McKellen back in the old
>   days.

While she doesn't go into detail on why she made this design decision, it seems clear that it's her personal aesthetic choice. As you can see in this promotional photo from the first X-Men movie, Magneto's cape was asymmetrical from the beginning:

[image]